# How to Use OpenZeppelin's ERC721Votes in an NFT Minter Contract

Tags: nft, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm trying to incorporate the new [draft-ERC721Votes](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/draft-ERC721Votes.sol) in my NFT minter contract called `NFTVotes.sol`

When `draft-ERC721Votes.sol` is inherited in  the minter contract, VS Code is gives the following error:

`Derived contract must override function "_afterTokenTransfer". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.`

Why does this error occur?

1. Here is my minter contract `NFTVotes.sol`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

// NOT NEEDED ANYMORE: import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/draft-ERC721Votes.sol"; 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";


// DAO Governance Token and Minter Contract 
// VS Code gives an error of: "Derived contract must override function "_afterTokenTransfer". 
// Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types." 
// Only happens when I include ERC721Votes
contract NFTVotes is ERC721Votes, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, Pausable, Ownable, ERC721Burnable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("NFTVotes", "NFTV") EIP712("NFTVotes", "1")  {}

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }
    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

The error seems to occur from the [ERC721Enumerable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.5.0/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol) import. When it's removed, the error disappears. I also realized that `draft-ERC721Votes`  does contain '_afterTokenTransfer`:

2. `ERC721Enumerable` excerpt

```
abstract contract ERC721Votes is ERC721, Votes {
    /**
     * @dev Adjusts votes when tokens are transferred.
     *
     * Emits a {Votes-DelegateVotesChanged} event.
     */
    function _afterTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal virtual override {
        _transferVotingUnits(from, to, 1);
        super._afterTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
```

3. So adding the following to `NFTVotes.sol` makes the VS code error disappear:

```
    function _afterTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override(ERC721, ERC721Votes)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
```

4. My question is why? And is this the correct way to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not the correct way to fix it.
For starters, you call `_beforeTokenTransfer` in a `_afterTokenTransfer` call which is completely wrong and can be disastrous.

change it to `_afterTokenTransfer`.

Also, notice how you override the function: `override(ERC721, ERC721Votes)`, this should not work if you do import `ERC721Enumerable`, so add `ERC721Enumerable` to this list.
Note that you should first import ERC721 since it's the base class, afterward you can import ERC721Enumerable and ERC721Votes, and the last class you import will be the first to be called in a super class, (but it doesn't matter in your case).

##### Now why it happens

Let's simplify the problem, look at the following 2 contracts:

```
contract Dad {
    function eat() {
        //eat like dad
    }
}

contract Mom {
    function eat() {
        //eat like mom
    }
}
```

Both those contracts implement the function eat, and if we create this contract:

```
contract Parent is Dad, Mom {
    
}
```

and you call `parent.eat()` the solidity compiler would not know which implementation to call. This is why you have to override the function and specify which contract, Dad or Mom, will be called first in case of a super call (this is where the line `override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721Votes)` comes in, it goes from right to left so ERC721 will be last, don't get confused).